# How to match Navigation bar with status bar ios7

Tags: ios7, statusbar, navigationbar

I am developing a UINavigationController based app where one of the view i am presenting is modal where i need a navigation bar which i have manually added but problem is the statusbar and navigation bar colors are different and both are translucent though, is there a way to set both same the way they appear on UINavigationController?

Comment: The solution I have opted for now is have added a view of 20point height on the statusbar and set its color to match the navigationbar thought i know this isnt the right solution.

Comment: you can set color of status bar...which match to your navigationbar

Comment: doesnt work when its white and transluscent !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK finally I think this is what i had to do ,

on presenting the view modally I am loosing the transluscent status bar instead get a transparent status bar,and also required to add my own navigation bar,thats how ios7 handles the status bar now, what i did is I wrapped the modally presented view into a navigation controller and then presented it , no changes i was required to do in segues just embedded the modal view controller in a navigation controller.

To embed a view in navigation controller in storyboard , just select the view go to Editor menu and select embed in-> navigation controller option.